EXA Package problem. "exa has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!"
So yeah i recently reinstalled macos and so now i wanted to customize my terminal by z shell.
Then from tutorial that i was watching i needed to install exa package from https://the.exa.website/#installation
Command from that page: "brew install exa"
After pasting this command to terminal and running i caught error
Error: exa has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!
Can you help me please to solve this problem cause i don't really know what should i do
I tried to install package by homebrew https://the.exa.website/#installation

Well, as you see from the message, you can't install it via homebrew. It seems that there is no maintainer for exa anymore, so your best chances are to get the git repo at [https://github.com/ogham/exa])https://github.com/ogham/exa) and install it by yourself. An alternative would be to switch to its successor, eza, which seems to be supported by homebrew.

As @Mara said above, Exa is no longer maintained, so it has been disabled by Homebrew.
There is an alternative called Eza, which is linked on Exa's Github Readme. This is an actively maintained fork of Exa, so it will have all the same functionality, and then some.
It can be installed with Homebrew:
brew install eza
It can also be installed a variety of other ways, if your environment is configured such that Homebrew will not be compatible.

You'll probably also want to replace your alias.
You should be looking for lines like alias ls="exa --icons --long --header" in the ~/.zshrc or other shell profile config files, and replace exa with eza.

Exa is a better option than LSD if you have used Exa before. It is an identical replacement for Exa. LSD, on the other hand, is quite different.

exa is no longer maintained and has been disabled by Homebrew.
Use lsd instead. It's actively maintained and offers similar features for colorful directory listings.
Install lsd with Homebrew:
brew install lsd

This should fix your issue.
